# Resetting my "Since Last accident program with a button"

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a little code to count up from a specific date. How can i make it so when i click a button on my webpage it resets to 0 and then keep counting?

I have the following js code:

```
const second = 1000,
  minute = second * 60,
  hour = minute * 60,
  day = hour * 24;


let countUp = new Date('February 07, 2019 16:24:00').getTime(),
x = setInterval(function() {

  let now = new Date().getTime(),
      distance = now - countUp;

    document.getElementById('days').innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day)),
    document.getElementById('hours').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour)),
    document.getElementById('minutes').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute)),
    document.getElementById('seconds').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / (second));


}, second)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The problem is that you need to store the date somewhere. Right now it's being stored in the javascript file on the server, so when the user clicks the button, something on the server needs to update the stored value. For obvious reasons (security), a browser can't make changes to a file stored on the server by just saying "save file" or something. To answer this question, we'll need to know how you're serving the file. Your server needs a method that allows for updating the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the interval's timer handle and cancel it on click of the button. Convert your timer code to a function that creates a interval checker instead:

```
function createNewTimer(date){
  return setInterval(function() {

    let now = date,
        distance = now - countUp;

      document.getElementById('days').innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day)),
      document.getElementById('hours').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour)),
      document.getElementById('minutes').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute)),
      document.getElementById('seconds').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / (second));


  }, second);
}

var timerId = createNewTimer(new Date('February 07, 2019 16:24:00').getTime());

var element = // select your element
element.addEventListener('click', function() { 
  clearInterval(timerId);
  timerId = createNewTimer(new Date().getTime())
}, false);
```

This illustrates the basic idea of how to reset the timer and add variability to the start date of the time

Comment: This is a good suggestion if the webpage is not meant to be refreshed or loaded on more than once device. Once it's refreshed or loaded on another device, it will reset to 2/7 and will not have knowledge of when the button was clicked in the other session.

Comment: @nvioli nowhere in the question did he mention anything about persistence, page refreshes, etc, so why would we assume that's what he needs?

Comment: because those are constraints that apply to most webpages. Many beginner programmers don't understand that and think you can do server-side things in javascript. I'm not assuming that's what he needs; it's a good answer, just want to make sure OP understands the limitations.